# Android Parcelable readString() under the hood

Tags: android, parcelable

I have this simple model class here:

```
public class News implements Parcelable {
    private String title;
    private String content;

    public News(String title, String content) {
        this.title = title;
        this.content = content;
    }

    protected News(Parcel in) {
        title = in.readString();
        content = in.readString();
    }
}
```

Quite simple and works well. 
However, what I don't understand is, **how does `Parcel` know what to read when I say `readString()`?** Both the `title` and `content` are just `String`s and I call the exact same method. How come Android doesn't mix up the results?

Or do I have to specify an order in which I call the `in.readString()`s?

I'd like someone skilled to clear things up for me.

Comment: Yes, order matters. You specify it in the order in which you write the values.

Comment: Thank you. I uploaded a simple model here but the one I use is waaay more complex, so you might just have saved me hours of debugging :D
If you wish to make this an answer, please do so. The documentation says only that it reads a string, that's it.

Comment: see `Parcelable#writeToParcel`

Comment: I was just gonna close it as a duplicate, actually, since it's been addressed here before. Thanks, though.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, after checking the question you mentioned, indeed it was asked before. Just my googling skills failed me :( By the way why did the asker got so many downvotes there? it's a completely valid question.

Comment: That user got, I think, one downvote to begin with, but then they opened a question on https://meta.stackoverflow.com that was basically a rant about downvotes, and they made the mistake of linking directly to that particular question. The meta effect happened, and they just kinda brought more downvotes on themself.

Comment: Makes sense. It would be beneficial if a downvote would require comments on what to improve IMO but yeah -  ranting has never ever got anyone far.